# Source qualifier SQL override equivalent in ODI

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, informatica-powercenter, oracle-data-integrator

I have started using Oracle Data Integrator very recently. I was wondering if there are any options to write SQL override query in ODI like Informatica Source Qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

ODI 12c includes that concept out of the box. On the physical tab of a mapping, click on the source node (datastore). Then in the properties pane, there is the CUSTOM_TEMPLATE option under "Extract Options" menu. This allows to enter a custom SQL statement that will be used instead of the code generated by ODI.

It's a bit trickier for ODI 11g as it requires to use a different Knowledge Module. This blog post from David Allan explains how to do it and give a link to download the knowledge module : https://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/entry/odi_11g_simple_flexible_powerful

Comment: Thanks Jerome. I will look at that option.